# how to inner join 3 table

Tags: mysql, database, inner-join

how to join three table, i have 3 table which is buku, sedia, and perpus, buku has attribute idbuku, namapengarang, namabuku, penerbit, genre, and tahunterbit.perpus has attribute idperpus, namaperpus, and alamat.and sedia has attribute stok, idperpus, and idbuku
what I want to ask is I tried to inner join the 3 table with syntax

```
select * from buku inner join sedia where buku.idbuku =sedia.idbuku;
```

it works, but when I try

```
select * from buku inner join sedia where buku.idbuku =sedia.idbuku inner join perpus where sedia.idperpus = perpus.idperpus;
```

the code is error, it says warning : mysql_fetch_array() expected parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given on line 64.

can anyone told me what should I do?

its my php code that still dont work as it should be

```
<?php
                include "koneksi.php";

                        $cari=$_POST["cari"];
                        $rbut=$_POST["rbut"];

                    if (isset($cari)||isset($rbut)){
                        $sql = "select * from buku where $rbut like '%$cari%'inner join sedia on buku.IDbuku = sedia.IDbuku inner join perpus on sedia.IDperpus = perpus.IDperpus;";
                        $result = mysql_query($sql);
                    }
                    elseif(!isset($cari)||!isset($rbut)){
                        $cari=$_POST["cari"];
                        $rbut=$_POST["rbut"];
                        $sql = "select * from buku";
                        $result = mysql_query($sql);
                    }
                    echo "
                        <table border='1'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Nama Pengarang</th><th>Nama Buku</th><th>Penerbit</th><th>Genre</th><th>Tahun Terbit</th></tr>";

                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                        echo "
                        <tr>
                            <td>$row[IDbuku]</td>
                            <td>$row[NamaPengarang]</td>
                            <td>$row[NamaBuku]</td>
                            <td>$row[Penerbit]</td>
                            <td>$row[Genre]</td>
                            <td>$row[TahunTerbit]</td>
                        </tr>";
                    }
                    echo "
                        </table>";
                ?>
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of mysql_fetch_array(). While you are at it, note that there are very large deprecation warnings associated with it. Use PDO or Mysqli and read up on the usage.

Comment: Run it in your db to see if you get any result or not.

Comment: I have tried in db, it wont show anything, it says error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `where`condition must be an `on`:

```
select * 
from buku 
inner join sedia on buku.idbuku =sedia.idbuku 
inner join perpus on sedia.idperpus = perpus.idperpus;
```

see the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) for more information about the join syntax.

** UPDATE **
Your new query is wrong:

```
$sql = "select * from buku inner join sedia on buku.IDbuku = sedia.IDbuku inner join perpus on sedia.IDperpus = perpus.IDperpus where $rbut like '%$cari%'";
```

If you read the documentation you will see that the where statement must be after the joun statements.

Comment: thanks mate, it dont give any error message again ^_^